# JS Date picker scrollbar like in Google Photos on android

Tags: datepicker, scrollbar, google-photos

Google Photos (at least on android) has a floating month picker that appears once you start scrolling through photos.

I am not sure what the agreed terminology for it is though and am having a hard time finding an equivalent for a browser based application. Is there a equivalent JS widget or code example someone can point me to?